# MySQL remove duplicate data based on a column

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1055

***I am using MySQL 5.7.13***

I have following records in my database, and I want to filter out the records on the basis of single column(email_identifier). i.e. return only single record in case a particular column has duplicate value.

I am trying following query but it throws following error

```
mysql> select * from list_subscriber where list_master_id = 202 group by email_identifier;
```

ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db1.list_subscriber.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Ideally above query should return only 1 record and *with all the columns*.

**Please suggest how can I achieve this?**

**DATABASE ROW SAMPLE**

```
mysql> select * from list_subscriber where list_master_id = 202 limit 2\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                         id: 30518899
             list_master_id: 202
          unique_identifier: A
           email_identifier: xyz@yahoo.co.in
          mobile_identifier: 9195423432432
alternate_mobile_identifier: 
          region_identifier: 
            city_identifier: 
         country_identifier: 
             age_identifier: 
          gender_identifier: 
                   raw_data: {"user":"A","number":"919542342423","msg":"msg3","emailid":"xyz@vfirst.com"}
                 created_at: 2016-07-08 15:33:24
                 updated_at: 2016-08-11 14:55:52
                 deleted_at: NULL
*************************** 2. row ***************************
                         id: 30518901
             list_master_id: 202
          unique_identifier: J
           email_identifier: xyz@vfirst.com
          mobile_identifier: 919540077166
alternate_mobile_identifier: 
          region_identifier: 
            city_identifier: 
         country_identifier: 
             age_identifier: 
          gender_identifier: 
               raw_data: {"user":"J","number":"919540077166","msg":"msg4","emailid":"xyz@vfirst.com"}
                 created_at: 2016-07-08 15:34:49
                 updated_at: 2016-08-11 14:55:52
                 deleted_at: NULL
```

**UPDATE**

```
CREATE TABLE `list_subscriber` (
`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`list_master_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`unique_identifier` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`email_identifier` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`mobile_identifier` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`alternate_mobile_identifier` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT   NULL,
`region_identifier` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`city_identifier` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`country_identifier` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`age_identifier` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`gender_identifier` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`raw_data` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `list_subscriber_list_master_id_foreign` (`list_master_id`),
CONSTRAINT `list_subscriber_list_master_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY    (`list_master_id`) REFERENCES `list_master` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)   ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=66956432 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Can you post schema and information about "infinito_staging1.list_subscriber.id" this??

Comment: @cody123 added show create table, let me know if you need any other info.

Answer (score 0):

When doing `group by` you need to provide an [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) for each column, how else could MySQL choose one of two different values?

What you *should* do if you wan't to enforce that email is unique in your table is to tell MySQL that. Best way is to [add a unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html).

```
alter table list_subscriber add unique key unique_email (email_identifier);
```

This might fail, if you already have duplicates in your table. To find all emails that have duplicates run

```
select email_identifier, count(1) as cnt from list_subscriber group by email_identifier having cnt > 1;
```

That will give you all those emails and then you'll manually have to delete/merge the records.

Comment: I can not make any column unique, additionally duplicate check can be on any of the column, i have to do it via query only.

Answer (score 0):

About group by:

For example:

```
select a, b,c from abc group by a
```

In this situation you need **add aggregation function** to column b and c
Possibly you can **add column b and c to group by** like:

```
select a,b,c from group by a, b, c
```

Comment: ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db1.list_subscriber.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by